# I am looking for a fantasy novel about a girl with red hair and red palms

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading it somewhere around 2002. It is a fantasy series with a heroine who has red hair. In one scene, she reaches toward an apple hanging from a tree and somehow gains magical power from the Sun, turning her palm red. She does the same thing later with the Moon, turning her other hand red. She travels with a party to defeat some evil king or another.

I can also remember a scene where she uses her own life force and ages very quickly.

Can someone help me with finding the title of this book or series?

EDIT: I remembered that the girls name was Elena. I found the book and it is called Wit'ch Fire

Comment: Ah, you edited just as I finished typing my answer!

Comment: I believe Rosie Palms operates a B&B in The Shades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of James Celemen's *Wit'ch Fire*.

Someone else [asked a similar question](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2120120-solved-girl-with-bloodstained-hand-after-hitting-her-menstrual-cycle-fa) "Girl with bloodstained hand after hitting her menstrual cycle-fantasy-dark magic":

> am looking for the series that begins with a young girl who suddenly is reaching for an apple, then it shrives in her hand and she looks and it suddenly is turned red up to her forarm. [sic]

And [elsewhere someone asked](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=8031), "Name of Book about a young witch with a Red Hand":

> I've been searching for a book series (I know there were 3 of em). What I remember is a young witch with a red hand that faded everytime she used magic, a one armed gaurdian or juggler who helped her and about a demonic entity she was fighting.... part of the book she had to fight a evil being who had thousands of little spiders in her womb. I know it may sound like a crazy book series, but any help would be appreciated.

I can't find anything about her *other* hand becoming red, but a lot of the other information ties to it.

> Thirteen-year-old Elena is the daughter of kindly **orchard keepers** who have no idea their little girl is the reincarnated sorceress Sisa'kofa, "wit'ch of spirit and stone," dead for more than five centuries and now the world's last hope for defeating the dreaded Dark One and his minions.

For the record, this planned trilogy is now actually 5 books.

Comment: Although humorous on its own, did you intend your first link to be to a Youtube video clip from the Truman Show?

Comment: @Xantec Nope, that's hilarious. That hasn't been in my clipboard for a day or more. I'll fix it!